# How to add a network adapter to a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I have a machine running Fedora 22. The motherboard provides an Ethernet network adaptor, which I connect to our office network. I want to add an HP Ethernet 10Gb 2-port 560SFP+ Adapter to support a local subnet, but retain the original motherboard adaptor and connection to the office network.

Before adding the 560SFP+ card, ifconfig -a reports:

```
$ ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      inet 172.29.68.172  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.29.68.255
```

but after inserting the new card, that command reports entries for enpls0f0 and enpls0f1, but eno1 has gone.

How can I recover eno1?

Answer (score 1):

My first place to look would be in the BIOS and see if the new card has for some reason replaced or removed the BIOS entry

Comment: I've checked the BIOS but can't find a mention of the onboard network adaptor there.